# Why is the variance of a portfolio a quadratic form?

Tags: risk-management, modern-portfolio-theory

I was reading about MPT http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_portfolio_theory and notices that the total variance of a portfolio is $x' \Sigma x$,  where x is the weighting of the assets and $\Sigma$ the covariance of returns.

I'm trying to gain some intuition on why this is a quadratic for and not simply the sum of the individual assets risks multiplied by their weighting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you take the variance of a single asset it scales as a quadratic,
$$
var(\lambda X) = \lambda^2 var(X)
$$
so it's not surprising that the general case gives a quadratic form.

Answer (score 2):

If you take the a sample of historical asset returns as model for the risk then you can do two things:

1. You calculate $r_j = \sum_{i=1}^n w_i r_i^j$ thus for each scenario $j$ you aggregate the individual asset returns to get a scenario for the portfolio. Then you can calculate $Var(r_j)$ the variance of the sample of portfolio returns. This is the same as
2. you calculate the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ on the individual asset returns and then perform $x' \Sigma x$.

The result will be the same. In procedure 1) you will see that assets with positive correlation tend to increase or decrease the aggregate portfolio return in scenarios $j$ (positive covariance) - others will offset each other (negative covariance). This is how how covariance influences the variance of the portfolio return. In 1) you can see it plainly in each scenario (on average) and in 2) you have it translated into $\Sigma$.

This should answer why covariance enter the expression for the variance. For why it is a quadratic form: as Mark Joshi puts it: it is a straight forward generalization of the univariate situation.